# Tor stuck at 10%

Tags: bootstrapping

On device connected to the same router Orbot is able to connect and work correctly. On laptop Tor stuck at 10%. For configuration file I use copy of torrc.sample with bridges added.
I suppose in fresh installed Xubuntu firewall doesn't block anything by default.

```
Aug 27 12:57:10.191 [notice] Tor v0.2.6.9 (git-d41ab97294ec69c7) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1f and Zlib 1.2.8.
Aug 27 12:57:10.191 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 27 12:57:10.191 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 27 12:57:10.198 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 27 12:57:10.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 27 12:57:10.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 27 12:57:10.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Aug 27 12:57:10.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
Aug 27 12:57:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
Aug 27 12:57:11.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
Aug 27 13:02:21.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 7; recommendation warn; host B18E163C67A5063562xxxxxxEAC0BF64CFDD537 at 5.135.xxx.xx:443)
Aug 27 13:02:21.000 [warn] 7 connections have failed:
Aug 27 13:02:21.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
Aug 27 13:02:21.000 [warn]  2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state unknown state in HANDSHAKE
Aug 27 13:02:21.000 [warn]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

What could be the problem?
Last warnings mentioned TSL and SSL, but Tor didn't complain on OpenSSL version or whatever...